# How to calculate confidence intervals for logistic regression predictions? How does `statsmodels` do it in `summary_frame`?

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, python, likelihood-ratio, statsmodels

I am fitting a logistic regression in Python's `statsmodels` and want a confidence interval for the predicted probabilities. This has been easy to get using `prediction.summary_frame`, but how is `statsmodels` calculating those values? For instance, are they Wald confidence intervals? I think I would prefer likelihood ratio intervals.

(Then again, I want likelihood ratio intervals because they are preferred to Wald intervals when it comes to estimating the logistic regression parameters. Perhaps this is a non-issue when it comes to the predictions.)

Comment: statsmodels GLM uses wald confidence intervals for the linear prediction and then transforms them using the inverse link function. I have seen likelihood profile intervals only for a single parameter.

Comment: This might be a case where Bayesian intervals are better, or some approximations such as parametric bootstrapping. Don't know about Python ...

Comment: @Josef Could you please expand on that? For instance, do you mean that the package uses Wald confidence intervals on the regression parameters before sending those upper and lower linear combinations through the inverse link function? (Three years later, this problem matters to me once again.)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What would you see as “parametric” about the bootstrap here?

Comment: @Dave Yes, partially. statsmodels uses cov_params (asymptotic covariance of the parameter estimates) to compute the standard error for the linear predictor. Then confidence intervals for the linear predictor are transformed by the inverse link function to get confidence intervals for the prediction in response space. This works when the prediction depends only on one distribution parameter (linear predictor) as in GLM. For other cases, e.g. multiple distribution parameters and predicting other nonlinear function, inference and confidence intervals are based on delta method.

Comment: Note, there were some changes for GLM get_prediction in 0.14, see notes in  https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.get_prediction.html . Implementation comments about the get_prediction methods are in https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7833